# Tamaño de elementos dentro de GridLayout - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un problema, No me había familiarizado mucho con java, Estoy programando en Eclipse, el problema es que Cuando utilizo la clase GridLayout para posicionar los elementos, todo esta bien, menos el alto que se le pone por defecto a los elementos como, JButton o los JTextField.
Hay alguna forma de controlar ese comportamiento?

```
    public laminaInfo() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    header = new JLabel("Informacion sobre el usuario");
    header.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    header.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel laminaForm = new JPanel();

    laminaForm.setLayout(new GridLayout(5 , 4));


    add(laminaForm, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    nombre  = new JLabel("Nombre");

    inputNombre = new JTextField(20);

    apellido = new JLabel("Apellido");

    inputApellido = new JTextField(20);

    edad = new JLabel("edad");
    inputEdad = new JTextField(20);

    genero = new JLabel("Sexo");

    String generoLista[] = {"Hombre", "Mujer"};

    combo = new JComboBox(generoLista);

    agregar = new JButton("Imprimir");

    laminaForm.add(nombre);
    laminaForm.add(inputNombre);
    laminaForm.add(apellido);
    laminaForm.add(inputApellido);
    laminaForm.add(edad);
    laminaForm.add(inputEdad);
    laminaForm.add(genero);
    laminaForm.add(combo);
    laminaForm.add(agregar);





}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has realizado para controlarlo? ¿Nos muestras algo de código para guiarte por el buen camino?

Comment: Para controlarlo, pues nada la verdad, pero e intentado utilizar el metodo setPreferedSize(); pero sigue igual. Ya esta ahí el código de dicha lamina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar mejor [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), que permite controlar mucho mejor este tipo de comportamientos, así podrás poner el tamaño que quieras a tus botones y si te hará caso con "setPreferredSize()", ya que GridLayout ocupa todo el espacio de su contenedor y no podrás hacer nada para cambiarlo.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como usarlo siguiendo tu codigo:

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel header = new JLabel("Informacion sobre el usuario");
    header.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    header.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel laminaForm = new JPanel();

    laminaForm.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

    add(laminaForm, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel nombre  = new JLabel("Nombre");

    JTextField inputNombre = new JTextField(20);

    JLabel apellido = new JLabel("Apellido");

    JTextField inputApellido = new JTextField(20);

    JLabel edad = new JLabel("edad");
    JTextField inputEdad = new JTextField(20);

    JLabel genero = new JLabel("Sexo");

    String generoLista[] = {"Hombre", "Mujer"};

    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(generoLista);

    JButton agregar = new JButton("Imprimir");
    agregar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;        
    laminaForm.add(nombre, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    laminaForm.add(inputNombre, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    laminaForm.add(apellido, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    laminaForm.add(inputApellido, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    laminaForm.add(edad, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    laminaForm.add(inputEdad, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    laminaForm.add(genero, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    laminaForm.add(combo, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    laminaForm.add(agregar, c);
```

Quedando algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora ya si que puedes cambiar el size y las constantes de [GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) para ponerlo a tu gusto a lo alto o ancho.

Comment: Gracias, lo solucione